# Strange issue with custom email template in magento

Tags: magento, email, templates, send, partition-problem

Hi for some need i need to set up a new email template with new header and footer with 
for this i have create a new template in

`configuration->transaction emails`  and `crate a new template`

with the following code

```
<html>

<body bgcolor="#8d8e90">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#8d8e90">
  <tr>
    <td><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>

                <td width="144"><a href= "http://yourlink" target="_blank"><img src="images/logo_3.png" width="144" height="76" border="0" alt=""/></a></td>
                <td width="393"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td height="46" align="right" valign="middle"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="57%" align="right"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#68696a; font-size:8px; text-transform:uppercase"><a href= "http://yourlink" style="color:#68696a; text-decoration:none"><strong></strong></a></font></td>
                            <td width="39%" align="right"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#68696a; font-size:8px"><a href= "http://yourlink" style="color:#68696a; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase"><strong>Welcome to elu by cristina nicoletti </strong></a></font></td>
                            <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td height="30"><img src="images/PROMO-GREEN2_01_04.jpg" width="393" height="30" border="0" alt=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#68696a; font-size:36px; text-transform:uppercase"><strong>shopelubycn</strong></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><a href= "http://yourlink" target="_blank"><img src="images/PROMO-GREEN2_02.jpg" alt="" width="598" height="249" border="0"/></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="58%" align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="95%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td height="35" align="left" valign="middle" style="border-bottom:2px dotted #000000"><font style="font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color:#000000; font-size:25px"><strong><em>Main Feature Story</em></strong></font></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top"><font style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:13px; line-height:21px">Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio t non</font> <font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#05bcda; font-size:12px; line-height:20px"><a href= "http://yourlink" style="color:#05bcda; text-decoration:none"><strong><em>read more} </em></strong></a></font></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td height="10" style="border-bottom:4px solid #d0d1d3"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td height="10"></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="43%"><img src="images/NEWSLETTER GREEN01.jpg" width="150" height="130" border="0" alt=""/></td>
                                <td width="57%" align="left" valign="top"><font style="font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color:#05bcda; font-size:20px"><strong><em>Second feature</em></strong></font> <br />
                                  <font style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:13px; line-height:21px">Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quisn</font> <font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#05bcda; font-size:12px; line-height:20px"><a href= "http://yourlink" style="color:#05bcda; text-decoration:none"><strong><em>read more} </em></strong></a></font><font style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:13px; line-height:21px">&nbsp; </font></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td height="10" style="border-bottom:4px solid #d0d1d3"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td height="10"></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="43%"><img src="images/NEWSLETTER GREEN02.jpg" width="150" height="130" border="0" alt=""/></td>
                                <td width="57%" align="left" valign="top"><font style="font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color:#05bcda; font-size:20px"><strong><em>Second feature</em></strong></font> <br />
                                  <font style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:13px; line-height:21px">Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quisn</font> <font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#05bcda; font-size:12px; line-height:20px"><a href= "http://yourlink" style="color:#05bcda; text-decoration:none"><strong><em>read more} </em></strong></a></font><font style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:13px; line-height:21px">&nbsp; </font></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                        <td width="5%" style="border-right:2px dashed #95989a">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
                <td width="35%" align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="82%" align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td height="10"> </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://yourlink" target="_blank"><img src="images/NEWSLETTER-GREEN03.jpg" alt="buy her" width="180" height="144" border="0"/></a></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="79%" bgcolor="#05bcda"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width="5%"></td>
                                    <td width="90%" height="10"></td>
                                    <td width="5%"></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td align="center"><font style="font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:16px"><strong>SPECIAL
                                      COLUMN</strong></font></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td height="5" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff"></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td height="5"></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top"><font style="font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:14px; line-height:21px">Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, <font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; font-size:12px; line-height:20px"><a href= "http://yourlink" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none"><strong><em>read more} </em></strong></a></font></font></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="http://yourlink" target="_blank"><img src="images/NEWSLETTER GREEN04.jpg" alt="view more offers" width="129" height="43" style="display:block" border="0"/></a></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table></td>
                                <td width="9%" >&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                            </table></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                    <td width="8%">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="images/PROMO-GREEN2_07.jpg" width="598" height="7" style="display:block" border="0" alt=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="13%" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="14%" align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#010203; font-size:9px; text-transform:uppercase"><a href= "http://yourlink" style="color:#010203; text-decoration:none"><strong>UNSUBSCRIBE </strong></a></font></td>
              <td width="2%" align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#010203; font-size:9px; text-transform:uppercase"><strong>|</strong></font></td>
              <td width="9%" align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#010203; font-size:9px; text-transform:uppercase"><a href= "http://yourlink" style="color:#010203; text-decoration:none"><strong>ABOUT </strong></a></font></td>
              <td width="2%" align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#010203; font-size:9px; text-transform:uppercase"><strong>|</strong></font></td>
              <td width="10%" align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#010203; font-size:9px; text-transform:uppercase"><a href= "http://yourlink" style="color:#010203; text-decoration:none"><strong>PRESS </strong></a></font></td>
              <td width="2%" align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#010203; font-size:9px; text-transform:uppercase"><strong>|</strong></font></td>
              <td width="11%" align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#010203; font-size:9px; text-transform:uppercase"><a href= "http://yourlink" style="color:#010203; text-decoration:none"><strong>CONTACT </strong></a></font></td>
              <td width="2%" align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#010203; font-size:9px; text-transform:uppercase"><strong>|</strong></font></td>
              <td width="17%" align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#010203; font-size:9px; text-transform:uppercase"><a href= "http://yourlink" style="color:#010203; text-decoration:none"><strong>STAY CONNECTED</strong></a></font></td>
              <td width="4%" align="right"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/PROMO-GREEN2_09_01.jpg" alt="facebook" width="22" height="19" border="0" /></a></td>
              <td width="5%" align="center"><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/PROMO-GREEN2_09_02.jpg" alt="twitter" width="23" height="19" border="0" /></a></td>
              <td width="4%" align="right"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/PROMO-GREEN2_09_03.jpg" alt="linkedin" width="20" height="19" border="0" /></a></td>
              <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#231f20; font-size:8px"><strong>Head Office &amp; Registered Office | Company name Ltd, Adress Line, Company Street, City, State, Zip Code | Tel: 123 555 555 | <a href= "http://yourlink" style="color:#010203; text-decoration:none">customercare@company.com</a></strong></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

in this i need to send some variables 
which are

```
Customer Name =    {{var customer_name}}  <br/>
Customer Name  = {{var customer_email}}  <br/>
Product Name =   {{var pro_name}} <br/>
Product Price  =  {{var pro_price}} <br/>
Product Color =  {{var color}}  <br/>
Product  Size =   {{var size}}  <br/>
Preferred Contact =  {{var preferred}}  <br/>
 Customer Enquiry =  {{var comment}}   <br/>
```

when i am sending only these variables the email is sent. but the problem is when i am sending the email template i am not getting any email.

but when i again copy the variables only then i got two emails with the email template and a second one with the variables .

i cant understand why only template not sent in email

Comment: first you will get these variable on controller after that those variable automatic get our value and email working.

Comment: yes i have those in my controller  , but the problem is my email templat enot sent when i am using that

Comment: it seems like it store as a draft in magento , and when i use these varuibales obnly i got two mails one is of variabkle and other is off template

Comment: okay please define your variable like this on starting on template,

<!--@vars
{"var data.name":"Sender Name",
"var data.email":"Sender Email",
"var data.telephone":"Sender Telephone",
"var data.comment":"Comment"}
@-->